# Pick up items add to cart(Woocommerce) and send by email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form

I have contact form 7 integrated with Woocommerce so that it is possible to receive requests for quotations by email. The problem is that I cannot get the products that are added to the cart to be sent by email.
If the customer does not tell me what they want in any of the fields, I will not have access to what has been added to the cart, for example.

[Cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUQpL.png)

In the print there is the information that the customer will have to fill out in addition to the Desired Products field, as it was the only alternative I entered to get around the problem, would be the customer typing the desired products.
Note: I do not make sales directly through woocommerce, my company provides services and sells products on order.

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdfT1.png)

Currently this is my form template in contact form 7:
[Currently Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znYvz.png)

This is the body of my email:
[Body of my email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgm3n.png)

I recently joined the company and never had contact with wordpress, I have searched on several sites, but without success.